# Page View Controller viewDidLoad() Issues

Tags: swift, datasource, uipageviewcontroller

I'm learning Swift/Xcode and trying to create an app with three pages that you can swipe back and forth using a Page View Controller. The issues I'm having lie in the UIViewController subclass, more specifically the viewDidLoad() function. I'm getting errors like "value of type 'NameOfMyClass' has no member datasource/delegate" and "use of unresolved identifier "setViewControllers". I've followed many tutorials and checked other posts but no one seems to be having these issues. When I attempted to run this I would get a black screen, and now I get a terminated due to signal 15 error.

Here's the relevant code where the errors are popping up:

```
import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIViewController, 
UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        return [self.VCInstance(name: "MissionOne"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "MissionTwo"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "MissionThree")]

    }()

    private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
     nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self //...has no member 'dataSource' error
        self.delegate = self //...has no member 'delegate' error
        if let MissionOne = viewControllerList.first {
            setViewControllers([MissionOne], direction: .forward, animated: 
         true, completion: nil) 
         //use of unresolved indentifier 'setViewControllers' error
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

The other issue I'm having, and it may be related, is that the Page View Controller is not accepting/recognizing my class file to set as the custom class in the story board.

Thanks in advance for any insight or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

your RootPageViewController is subclass of UIViewController, not a UIPageViewController

Comment: Fixed it indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looks to me that you are mixing two different controllers here.

What you want to do is add 3 RootPageViewController to a UIPageViewController, yet here you are trying to add 3 RootPageViewControllers to a RootPageViewController!

One way to fix it is to have a RootPageViewController and a separate UIPageViewController which will contain all RootPageViewControllers like so:

```
// This is a UIPageViewController containing all RootPages
class PagesViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        return [RootPageViewController.VCInstance(name: "MissionOne"),
            RootPageViewController.VCInstance(name: "MissionTwo"),
            RootPageViewController.VCInstance(name: "MissionThree")]

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        if let MissionOne = viewControllerList.first {
            setViewControllers([MissionOne], direction: .forward, animated: 
     true, completion: nil) 
        }

    }
}
```

And the RootPageViewController which will be added in the UIPageViewController above:

```
// This is a UIViewController representing a single page
class RootPageViewController: UIViewController {

    static func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    }

    // Do what you need a page to do...
}
```

With such a construction you will have all your errors solved and you will also be able to use `PagesViewController` as custom class in your Storyboard!

Comment: I definitely had some controller type mismatching going on. It was fixed from just changing the subclass type to the correct UIPageViewController, like you have in your example code. Thank you for the example!